# How can I publish my node.js a.p.i to iis?

Tags: node.js, iis

I am making an api with node js and I need to publish it to a server. I have been looking at how to do it and there is a lot of information about doing it on platforms like heroku but I can't get it up to the server that I use in my work. This is a Windows Server 2012 r2 and works with IIS. I followed the steps given in the documentation https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode. But when I raise the server I receive an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzNWI.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [host node js on windows server (iis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266609/host-node-js-on-windows-server-iis)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your api pool doesn't have full permission to write.

```
give permission the edit to give the "IIS_IUSRS" group write permissions to that folder.
```

```
Go into the advanced settings menu and under Process Model -> Identity change the user account to a user that already has write permissions.
Allow, 'Full Control', for user 'IIS_IUSRS', from 'Advanced Security' upon right clicking you'r application root directory.
```