# How Can I keep a NextJS app running after I close the terminal?

Tags: iis, next.js, deployment, windows-server

I use windows server and ı want to deploy my app on it. Thanks to ııs ı deploy it but ı want to close Terminal or Vscode how can ı do it ?

Comment: Typical Node.js based web apps can all be hosted on IIS via HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: Okey but, ı want to run it with terminal but when ı close the terminal the program will not be close. this is what ı want .

Comment: What does terminal refer to? If nextjs is successfully published to iis, closing vscode will have no effect on the running of the application.

Comment: @samwu it's just work for "node server.js"

Comment: Then you only need to publish it to iis, closing the terminal and vscode will not affect its running, you can refer to this link on how to deploy to iis: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163476/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163476/13336642).