# DNS address could not be found when deploying node application with iisnode

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns, windows-server-2012-r2, iisnode

I have a machine running Windows Server 2012 R2 and I have been trying to deploy a simple node application using iisnode.

I have tried to achieve this in 2 ways. The first one, set up IIS as a reverse proxy. For this, I followed the article "https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b".

The second way, using iisnode which is described here: [host node js on windows server (iis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266609/host-node-js-on-windows-server-iis).

I followed both methods step by step, but I got the same result, ["DNS address could not be found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocQBQ.png)

I have tried to fix this in the following ways:

- clear the host cache in my browser
- restart "DNS Client"
- change DNS settings (set DNS server address to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, which led brought "DNS address could not be found" errors when I tried to access any website, not just mine)
- delete files from the "etc" folder (I restarted my computer afterward)
- flush, renew, reset the DNS, which did not finish successfully, here is the response that I got:[screenshot of Windows Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESb0T.png)

I can't figure out why I am getting the "The operation failed and no adapter is in the state permissible for this operation" error. When I run "ipconfig /all" they show up fine. Is there something wrong with the firmware/drivers or maybe there is something that I have not set correctly in the IIS Manager?